# Django/Python : Need to Pass integer variables from the Django view to a template

Tags: python, html, django

I have two variable passcount & count in my python function that i need to render on HTML. I am able to pass a list 'matrix' to HTML but not these two variables.

```
html = t.render(Context({'matrix': matrix},{'passcount': passcount}, {'count': count}))
```

In the html page, i have used

Compliance Status : {{ passcount }}/{{ count }}

I am unable to figure out the mistake.

Comment: `html = t.render(Context({'matrix': matrix, 'passcount': passcount, 'count': count}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html = t.render(Context({'matrix': matrix, 'passcount': passcount, 'count': count}))
```